# To finish a function; return void or break loop?

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm showing you two examples:

Example A:

```
protected void mostrarCms(int idCms) {
    LinearLayout variableContent = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.variableContent);

    loopDeCms:
    for (int i=0; i<variableContent.getChildCount();i++){
        View fillActual = variableContent.getChildAt(i);
        if (fillActual instanceof WebView){
            WebView wbActual = (WebView) fillActual;
            if (wbActual.getContentDescription().toString().equals("cms_id_"+idCms)){
                wbActual.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break loopDeCms;
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

Example B:

```
protected void mostrarCms(int idCms) {
    LinearLayout variableContent = (LinearLayout) productView.this.findViewById(R.id.variableContent);

    for (int i=0; i<variableContent.getChildCount();i++){
        View fillActual = variableContent.getChildAt(i);
        if (fillActual instanceof WebView){
            WebView wbActual = (WebView) fillActual;
            if (wbActual.getContentDescription().toString().equals("cms_id_"+idCms)){
                wbActual.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return;
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

Which one of those both is recommended? Note that this code is from Android, so resources used / freed or not, actually matter.

Comment: 1. I never use a label when simple `break` suffices. 2. If I'm sure, this the last thing I need to do (even when the method gets extended), then I use return. Most of the time it's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case it doesn't matter. I guess that's a matter of style. I would use `break` so in case a new code is added after the for loop only the loop will end and not the whole method.

Think about the coder which will extend this code and add some functionality after the `for` loop. If you use the `return` statement the coder will have to waste time figuring out whether the method must return or you just preferred it over a `break` for style reasons. If you use `break` the future coder (which might be you) will be much more at ease adding logic after the `for` loop. This is why I prefer `break` and not `return`.

Performance wise it doesn't make any difference for 2 reasons:

1. There would probably be no performance issue here as this is very minor.
2. Even if there were performance issues - the compiler would probably know how to optimize.

It also doesn't matter resource-wise because either way, the scope of the method finishes and resources are allowed to be garbage collected when they're out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to exit the function then `return` is the best thing to do.

`break` only takes you out of the immediate loop so your control flow can break if future changes mean that your loop becomes nested inside another one. Always future proof your code as much as you can.

Answer (score 2):

Since the method does not do anything else after the loop (and shouldn't), using `return` is the cleaner option. Using `break` would imply that the processing will continue after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just personal favor. I personally try to avoid return statements anywhere not near the end of a function. If you want to add code to this function or extend the functionality a return in the head of the function could give you a lot headache.